# How get string before symbol

Tags: php, explode, strstr

I have strings

```
TEST #1 - Description
TEST #2 / Description
...
```

I need get string before `#` but with `#1`, output: `TEST #1`

```
strstr($str, '#', true);
```

These code output: **TEST** i need **TEST #1**

Comment: I think it is posible with preg_match but i dont know how make.

Comment: you could just explode on space.

Comment: @rtfm: Yes, however I anticipated the _"but sometimes there is no space"_ or _"doesn't work for `TEST-#1`"_.

Comment: @Shoxa please explain the variability of your input data, so that we can provide an accurate method without "guessing" what your strings look like.  Can we possibly use `^[^-/]+(?= )`?

Comment: you may assume what you like, ill base any answer on the actual code provided @AbraCadaver

Comment: or `^\D+\d+` ? It is best to give us realistic sample input data.

Comment: @Shoxa If you are satisfied with AbraCadaver's answer please mark it with the green tick.  If you would like to receive more answers/support, please improve your question by addressing the comments/concerns under your question.

Answer (score 1):

If the format is consistent (**word** **space** **#** **digits**) then:

```
$parts  = explode(' ', $str);
$result = $parts[0] . ' ' . $parts[1];
```

I assume the number can be multiple digits, so you'll need regex:

```
preg_match('/[^#]+#\d+/', $str, $match);
echo $match[0];
```

If you need multiple from one string then:

```
preg_match_all('/[^#]+#\d+/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Either way you are matching:

- `[^#]+` one or more `+` NOT `^` `#` characters
- Followed by `#` character
- Followed by one or more `+` digits `\d`